# How can I change color of tinymce background onchange using query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

I have a form with various input fields and if they change I want to change the background color

I use the following code which does what I need

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('textarea, input, select').change(function () {
        $(this).css({ 'background': '#D6FFD6' });
    });
});
```

The problem comes with one of my fields which is a tinymce field

This is not affected by my code

If I inspect the element of the `TinyMCE` field the actual data is held in a hidden textarea and the text that shows is in an iframe

Is there any way I can change the background on change and if so how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the body background color you can use:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f0f0f0';
```

To get the active editor as a jQuery element, just use:

```
$(tinymce.activeEditor)
```

**Edit:**

You have to handle events separately, because textarea elements are replaced by the editor (this works on v4 version):

```
$('textarea, input, select').change(function () {
    $(this).css({ 'background': '#D6FFD6' });
});

tinymce.activeEditor.on('change', function(){
    this.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = '#D6FFD6';
});
```

**Last edit:**

To get it work, you have to register events once `window` is loaded, like this:

```
// this is for v3
$(window).load(function() { 
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.onChange.add(function(){ this.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = '#D6FFD6' }); 
});
```

Comment: That's a very useful start thanks. It changes the background color. But I can't work out how to call it using myscript. At present I'm monitoring for changes to textarea, input & select I also need to check when the tinymce changes

Comment: The textarea input is your tinymce editor, so I think you can do something like `$(tinymce.activeEditor).on('change', function(){ ... });`

Comment: Let me to understand it correctly. You have some form-type elements. One of these are a tinymce textarea. And you want, if some of this elements are changed, change background color of the element changed? Is it correct?

Comment: that's exactly right. whenever a form element has been changed i want the background color of that element to change

Comment: I edited the answer. I think you can solve it with that piece of code 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77795/discussion-between-mjsolo-and-kmsdev).